# AWS ECS runTask override port Mappings

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have Lambda function that executes on schedule.

```
let params = {
    taskDefinition: taskDefinition,
    cluster: process.env.cluster,
    startedBy: 'lambda',
    count: process.env.count || 1,
    overrides: {
        containerOverrides: [{
            name: containerName,
            command: [
                '/bin/bash',
                '/usr/share/nginx/html/console/cronjobs/' + process.env.command
            ]
        }]
    }
};

if (typeof memory !== 'undefined') {
    params.overrides.containerOverrides[0].memory = parseInt(memory);
}

ecs.runTask(
    params,
    (error, data) => {}
);
```

It tries to start new Task from existing Task Definition. Problem is that one of Docker containers are already running with this Task Definition (constant run, not auto-exit) and uses Port Mappings that are set in Task Definition (E.g. 80 => 8080).

How can I run same Task Definition and ignore/override Port Mappings?

Or is there better way to start Task and run single bash command inside it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way at the moment to override the port mappings when running a new task. The allowed values you can override are listed here: [ContainerOverride documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerOverride.html)

To achieve what you want, you should keep a second task definition with you desired port mappings or use dynamic port mapping so there are no conflicts when running the ephemeral task.